# Events was not working properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, events, dom-events

I created a simple event script, which changes the image when clicked on the button. But unfortunately not changing, please help.

Error: I am not getting any error message also , just it was not changing the image.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events Practise</title>
    <style>
     #imtest{
     width:100px;
     height:150px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h4> This a practise page of Events and event handlers </h4>
    <p> Hi this the practise page that changes the Html and Css contents in the page by Using the JavaScript </p>
    <img id="imtest" src="marni.jpg" alt="Image corrupted">
    <button onclick="eventtest()">Change Image</button>
    <script>
        function eventtest()
        {
                var imt = document.getElementById("imtest");
                imt.onclick = change;
        }
        function change()
        {
            var imtchng = document.getElementById("imtest");
            imtchng.src = "marni1.png";
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I created a simple event script , which changes the image when clicked
>   on the button

No you've created a script which set's a click handler on the image when the button is clicked and after that when the image is changed it will change.

If you want to change the image directly by clicking just set the click handler on it.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification !! Now i understood where i have committed mistake :-)

Comment: I already accepted , but It shows that "I do not have 15 reputation points , so votes are recorded " some thing like this !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the `imt.onclick = change` line you are forgetting the parentheses after the `change`. Replace it with `change()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        function eventtest()
        {
change();
        }
        function change()
        {
            var imtchng = document.getElementById("imtest");
            imtchng.src = "marni1.png";
        }

    </script>

or

   <button onclick="change()">Change Image</button>
```